# Best practice when doing user research with surveys?

Tags: user-research, surveys

Could you suggest best practice when doing user reasearch with surveys with open questions?

**Context** a web page has (unexpectedly) a lot of visitors we know nothing about. This page is not listed in the navigation and there were no SEO efforts to improve its ranking in search engines. The topic of the page is a common topic also for other pages.

We were wondering why does this page have so many visitors. One idea was to ask a single open question in a survey in order to find out what the visitors are looking for. The survey will be integrated on the page (as a widget) or will be shown as a popup. The exact implementation is yet to be decided. Is there a best practice you can suggest for this scenario?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for book suggestions is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: The question was reworded to fit the rules.

Comment: Could you add to your question some details about how you plan to administer the survey? Will it be a popup on the page? Will you email it to a set of people?

Comment: It will be on the page, because we have no visitors contact data, so we can't send it per email.

Answer (score 0):

After building and running two major web intercept surveys, it still seems very much a process of trial and error. We are always adjusting these surveys based on user response and business needs.

But here are two lists of references:

- https://theblog.adobe.com/top-10-books-ux-research/
- https://uxdesign.cc/ux-books-on-research-strategy-97d65c2ff5b

I'd like to know which reference you found most useful.

Comment: The article from the Adobe blog was what I was looking for! Thank you